# Puppeteer proxy on Heroku

Tags: heroku, web-crawler, puppeteer

I am looking for a solution to anonymous a puppeteer web crawler deployed on Heroku. Locally I have Tor running on my local computer and re-routing traffic through the '127.0.0.1', 9050 port. Now I can not reproduce this on my Heroku app after deploying. Any thoughts on how to anonymize web crawler on heroku?

Answer (score 2):

Running a proxy is against Heroku's [Acceptable Use Policy](https://www.heroku.com/policy/aup) and will get your account shut down.

> 20. Use the Service to operate an "open proxy" or any other form of Internet proxy service that is capable of forwarding requests to any End User or third party-supplied Internet host;

Comment: Isn't this only applicable if you function as a proxy for third party's? I will not forward to any end user or third party, only the crawler itself will use a proxy?

Comment: This is probably a grey area. You may want to contact them directly.